# "Add to favorites" functionality for database table retrieved items using mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm populating some table rows from my database as html table rows using the following php example(for summarizing the code, I haven't included the mysql connection)

Populating results:

```
  $conn = //connected to db successfully
  <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
  $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
  ?>
  <table>
  do { ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $rows['column1']; ?></td><td><?php echo $rows['column2']; ?></td>
  <td><button type="button" onclick="addToFav();">Add to my favorites</button></td>
  </tr>
  <?php }while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)); ?>
  </table>
```

According to above query in which I've retrieved information with several columns(I've used two columns in example above), if a user clicks on the "Add to my favorites" I want the item to be added to the logged in user favorites so the user can see that in the profile page. How should I insert the item information to e,g 'favorites' table according to that I'm using 'mysqli_fetch_assoc' solution for retrieving information from 'items_table'.
Besides, I would like to do the action(adding item information to favorites table)by AJAX.

I appreciate your guys helping me with the solution for inserting each item information(including several columns) in addition to the logged in user 'id' to 'favorites' table so it can be displayed correctly for each user profile.
I really appreciate if you could also provide a solution for "addToFav()" function for this case as well since I'm pretty new to AJAX.
Sorry if the question got a little broad.
Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $conn = //connected to db successfully
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    ?>
    <table>
    <?php 
    /**
     * mysqli_fetch_assoc returns next row as an associative array if it exists
     * 
     * also, alternate syntax for control structures
     */
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)): 
    ?> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['column1']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['column2']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="addToFav();">Add to my favorites</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: How can I give the insert(to 'favorites'tables) functionality to "Add to my favorites" button? Can you provide a function for "addToFav()" according to that I'm using mysqli_fetch_assoc? Thanks.